# How to prevent base layers from being edited?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, mapnik

I've made a local tile server (mapnik + postgis + tilecache).

Now i need to make use of some editing tool so that only newly created layer can be edited: users of this tool shouldn't have rights to edit "base" geographic layer (in order not to spoil it).

**edit:**

I'll try to explain my workflow better: i want to allow users create and edit some *specific* objects on the map (parts of network infrastructure i.e. routers, optic lines and so on), but the critical feature  is to prevent users from editing the geographic map.

So, in short, they shoud only be able to edit the layer with our data, but not the data from openstreetmpas (i still need it for being able to update it).

I'm using `JOSM` for now, but how can i disable base layer editing?

Comment: Is the OSM data stored in PostGIS? If not, how do you store your base layers?

Comment: @underdark i use this: first importing osm file to PostGis, then generating map.xml and it's being used by tilecache. i've made a picture of this: http://s53.radikal.ru/i139/1202/97/584a3b047eb1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your background map data is stored in PostGIS, the most obvious solution would be to create a PostGIS **user for JOSM that only has read** (and no write) **privileges** on the data. Thus, the database will take care that the users cannot change the data they are not supposed to edit.

Answer (score 0):

I am bit unclear on your workflow and what your question is.

In short: 
Depending what your base layer is (a GEOTIFF raster ? OSM data in a .osm file ? a postgis database) what formats your other layers are in, and at what point in your workflow you add those layers, will depend on your what tools to use that would enable your base layer to be that read-only (not editable by other users or programs).

Answers could be more specific if you are more specific on your base layers and workflow.

Comment: i've edited my question, hope this helps